# C# Window Loses Focus in Mono on Linux

Tags: linux, mono

I built a simple game using C# in Visual Studio based upon an old BASIC bomber game that has a main window, plus additional child windows that provide a map image and a group of settings.  This program runs fine in Windows.  However, when I run the program over on my Linux virtual machine using the "mono" command, the program will only run properly if none of the child windows are opened.  If any child window is opened and subsequently closed, the main window never regains focus.  None of the menu options or buttons function.  They are all grayed out.  The only recourse is to kill the process.  I am running Lubuntu 15.10 and according to the detail from the Synaptic Package Manager, the version of the various mono support libraries is 3.2.8.  I am more curious than anything to see if I just need to wait for more "System Window" support to be added to mono runtime.  Thanks in advance for any responses.

Additional notes - March 8, 2016

This is in response to the request for code that causes the behavior.

As my program is quite lengthy, I quickly built a simple C# program using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 that has a parent window and a child window called by the press of a button.  This sample program exhibits the identical behavior seen in my bomber program on Windows and Linux.

In Windows, when the child window is displayed and closed, the focus returns to the parent window and I can use the menu option provided to close the parent window and program.  However, when I port this program over to my Linux system (Lubuntu 15.10 running in a virtual machine), the parent window never regains focus once the child window is opened and then closed.

Here is the C# code for the parent (known as Form1)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ParentChild  
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Child testChild = new Child();
            testChild.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the supporting child class code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ParentChild
{
    public partial class Child : Form
    {
        public Child()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnChild_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that clarifies matters.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is difficult to answer as it doesn't contain any code. You'll need to post your code so that people can look at it and point out where the problem is. It's preferred that you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Try to add after the ShowDialog *this.BringToFront(); this.Focus();*

Comment: Gusman,  Thank you for the suggestion.  I tried adding the two statements.  However, when launching this program in my Lubuntu system, the controls on the parent window were still grayed out and the window still did not seem to have focus.  I will try out a few more things with the child.